# How to use "The New Yorker" font in regular LaTeX

Tags: fonts

How can I use "The New Yorker" font by Allen R. Walden (see [Fontspace](http://www.fontspace.com/allen-r-walden/new-yorker)) in regular LaTeX (not in LuLaTeX or XeLaTeX).

Comment: It is a lot of work to create the fd-, tfm-, ... files that are needed. However, what is the reason that you do not want to use lualatex.

Comment: LuLaTex not always works with texmaker and Mac since ugrading to El Capitan

Comment: Please be more specific as to what "not always works" about LuaLaTeX. Do you get error and/or warning messages? If so, what do these messages say? Which version of TeXmaker do you use?

Comment: Nothing happens. But I think I just found the reason: the path was wrong. no that I have changed it to "/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/universal-darwin/" it works. So, you would recommend using LuLaTeX?

Comment: Whatever else you may do, I strongly recommend you upgrade to MacTeX2015.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

#### New school

Use `autoinst` on `NEWYORKR.TTF`.  It creates all the files you need to use the font with (pdf)LaTeX.  You can invoke it like this:

```
autoinst -encoding=T1      \
         -ts1              \
         -noupdmap         \
         -nooldstyle       \
         -noproportional   \
         -nosmallcaps      \
         -noswash          \
         -notitling        \
         -nosuperior       \
         -noinferiors      \
         -nofractions      \
         -noornaments      \
         -target=./Install \
         -verbose          \
         NEWYORKR.TTF
```

Installed properly, you can have the following result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{NewYorker}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{T1}{NewYorker-TLF}{m}{n}
\clearpage
\xfonttable{TS1}{NewYorker-TLF}{m}{n}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

#### Old school

Create the `afm` and `pfb` files from the `ttf`-file and use `fontinst` which is somewhat more complex.  You have to write a `drv` file like:

```
\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
\recordtransforms{fny-rec.tex}

\substitutesilent{bx}{m}
\substitutesilent{b}{m}

\transformfont{fnyr8r}{\reencodefont{8r}{\fromafm{NewYorker}}}

\installfonts
\installfamily{T1}{fny}{}
\installfont{fnyr8t}{fnyr8r,newlatin}{t1}{T1}{fny}{m}{n}{}
\endinstallfonts

\installfonts
\installfamily{TS1}{fny}{}
\installfont{fnyr8c}{fnyr8r,textcomp}{ts1}{TS1}{fny}{m}{n}{}
\endinstallfonts

\endrecordtransforms
\bye
```

and a `map` generator file like:

```
\input finstmsc.sty
\resetstr{PSfontsuffix}{.pfb}
\adddriver{dvips}{fny.map}
\input fny-rec.tex
\donedrivers
\bye
```

Then you have to run `tex` on the `drv` and `map` files plus:

```
for filename in *.pl; do pltotf $filename; done
for filename in *.vpl; do vptovf $filename; done
```

Properly installed, you get:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand*{\rmdefault}{fny}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}

\begin{document}
\xfonttable{T1}{fny}{m}{n}
\clearpage
\xfonttable{TS1}{fny}{m}{n}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Next thing would be teach `fontinst` to grab the write glyphs from the fonts where the name in `afm` does not match `fontinst` expectation.

Comment: Hm, in which folder should I run the code? I have to run it in the Terminal of my Mac, or?

Comment: @feder80 - I did it in a temporary folder where I created also a sub-directory `./Install` before running the code.  I ran it in `bash` (I'm not on Mac.)

Comment: Ok, looks better, but I get some warnings and errors: "otfinfo: verbose: No such file or directory" or "otftotfm: warning: assuming --no-type1 since this font is TrueType-flavored
[WARNING] 'otftotfm' returned non-zero; something's wrong! at /Library/TeX/texbin/autoinst line 643."

Comment: @feder80 - Sorry, my bad, `-` is missing before `verbose`, I've updated my answer.  I had the warning as well, it worked anyways.

Comment: the installation works now, but in LaTeX I get the following errror: "! LaTeX Error: File `NewYorker.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)"

Comment: You're not really comparing like with like. You can use the quick method for `fontinst` in simple cases. However, the real advantage of avoiding the automatic solutions (both forms) is that you have a lot more control and can optimise the results. Going by `8r` inevitably loses characters in most cases, for example.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks!  There was a bug in the code and I had uploaded a wrong snap shot; both corrected.  You are right, using `8r` is not the best choice, but the font doesn't provide many characters (`t1testpage -o NewYorker.ps NewYorker.pfb`) so it is not necessary to do a surgery with customized `etx` files.

Comment: @feder80 - You have to install the created files into your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory; see [here](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) or [here](http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/Font_Installation) for instructions.

Comment: In that case `\input fontinst.sty
\needsfontinstversion{1.926}
\recordtransforms{xyz-rec.tex}
\latinfamily{xyz}{}
\endrecordtransforms
\bye` is probably enough for the driver file. (Where `xyz` is substituted appropriately.)

Comment: If you use autoinst, and have multiple otf files for the same family (roman, italic, bold etc.), only run it once for each font family, as the map file will be overwritten. So give autoinst all otf files of the family at once.

Comment: Note that you don't have to convert to PFB to use `fontinst`. You do have to create AFMs, but you can use the TTFs directly with pdfTeX. (If 'regular LaTeX' means not pdfTeX then this is irrelevant.)